# Vulkan window not opening at all

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

Okay so i tried a bunch of thing including removing my generic sizing system also i tried rewriting my vulkan header file but nothing works. I asked the smart/high tech open ai for a solution and it gave me more problems so.

The code inside the initVulkan is something i threw togheter that is supposed to not be needed. I am following along the vulkan learning side but i did some changes.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "main-window.h"

int main()
{
    MainWindow mWindow;

    try {
        mWindow.run();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
#pragma once

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>

class MainWindow
{
    public:
        void run()
        {
            initWindow();
            initVulkan();
            mainLoop();
            cleanup();
        }

        GLFWwindow* window;

    private:
        void initWindow()
        {
            const uint32_t width = 800;
            const uint32_t height = 600;

            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

            window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Window", nullptr, nullptr);

        }

        void initVulkan()
        {
            VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo{};
            createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;

            VkInstance instance;
            VkResult result = vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance);
            if (result != VK_SUCCESS)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create Vulkan instance!");
            }
        }

        void mainLoop()
        {
            while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
            {
                glfwPollEvents();
            }
        }
        
        void cleanup()
        {
            glfwDestroyWindow(window);
            glfwTerminate();
        }
};
```

Comment: I'm not putting this in my answer because it's orthogonal to what you asked, but putting all the function definitions into the header means that as soon as you include that header in another file, those symbols will be multiply defined.  You'll either need to mark the functions inline or push them into a main-window.cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling [`glfwInit`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__init.html#ga317aac130a235ab08c6db0834907d85e) anywhere.

If you look at the most basic GLFW [documentation](https://www.glfw.org/documentation.html) you'll see that you need to call that function before any other GLFW library function.

Additionally, if you want to use GLFW with Vulkan you should read [this guide](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/vulkan_guide.html) which details the additional steps you should be going through.